# Python, ndb: Keys in datastore are stored like this [datastore_types.Key.from_path(...)]

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm getting a json array of one or more Key ids (urlsafe key) through HTTP request. And now i wanna store the key/keys of this Id/Ids in a **UserListProperty** i defined. It extends the **UserProperty** i defined to, which extends **ndb.KeyProperty**.

So if i use the **UserProperty** with just one key.. everythings all right. The Key is stored in the datastore normaly and as an reference. But when i use the **UserListProperty** (even with just one key), the datastore stores it as: `[datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Example', 20L, u'User', 21L, _app=example~db')]`

Where do i store this key? It's in an attribute (reader) of another model instance List that has the UserListProperty.

Okay, so i think i must do something wrong either in the UserListProperty definition or in the way i write into this Property. I wanna show both:

```
class UserProperty(ndb.KeyProperty):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProperty, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._visible = False
        self._verbose_name = 'User key'


class UserListProperty(UserProperty):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserListProperty, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._repeated = True
        self._visible = False
        self._verbose_name = 'List containing user keys.'
```

---

```
for viewer in viewerlist:
    key = Key(urlsafe=viewer)
    if not key in list.reader:
        list.reader.append(key)
```

Hope someone can help me.. I read something about the db.ReferenceProperty and tried to put it in here (instead of KeyProperty). but it doesn't work. Maybe i did something wrong. Or it just doesn't help.

Comment: I can't understand what you think is wrong with the way it's storing the key. It looks absolutely fine to me. What are you expecting? (And why are you creating those property subclasses? They seem pointless, you could just set the attributes directly on the field definition.)

Comment: okay.. nice to hear, that the problem is not here. when i test it local everything act normal.. how it should be. but on the live system.. it doen't. it stores a new list.. but it doesn't store the attribute reader. so i have to search somewhere else.. thank you for your comment. so i'm not despair on the key thing.. but somewhere else ;)

Comment: i thought i have to expect that the key is shown like the userProperty show its key: agtkZXZ-bG9mdGlkYnIXCxIETG9mdBgUDAsSB0FjY291bnQYFQw Example: id=20 > User: id=21 and not like this notation: [datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Example', 20L, u'User', 21L, _app=example~db')] but if this is right.. because it's a list of keys. so thanks to answer so fast!

Comment: the thing is.. it writes in the attributes.. but can't read them as keys. so maybe i did the mistake by reading. but because it works local i wonder why it wouldn't work live.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your code actually just works. The string you see:

```
[datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Example', 20L, u'User', 21L, _app=example~db')]
```

looks like the repr() of a list containing one Key object, which is exactly what you wanted.

Maybe there's something wrong with the way you set up the rest of the code (e.g. the model class that defines the reader property)?

To access the entities referenced by a repeated KeyProperty (which is what you are doing) you would have to use a loop, e.g.

```
for k in list.reader:
    ex = k.get()
    ...use ex...
```

PS. I would not set self._repeated in your **init** like you do; I would pass it to the super call, like this:

```
super(UserListProperty, self).__init__(*args, repeated=True, **kwargs)
```

And what is _visible?  If you don't need it, maybe instead of defining trivial subclasses of KeyProperty, just use this:

```
reader = KeyProperty(Example, repeated=True)
```

PS. About ReferenceProperty, it's from the old db module, and best forgotten.